Is "fahren" non-idiomatic in this sentence?
Duolingo marked wrong my sentence Die Menschen gingen mit dem Auto nach Westdeutschland (as a translation of "The people went to West Germany by car.") suggesting as the correct answer Die Menschen fuhren mit dem Auto nach Westdeutschland.
Since I am pretty sure I have seen/heard gehen used with mit dem Auto, I thought this might be a mistake on Duolingo's part but I wanted to confirm my sentence is idiomatic. I don't think it was an issue with the scope as both "fuhren" and "gingen" are featured in this unit.

The confusion perhaps stems from the different meanings of "go/gehen":
"To go" in English means to change your whereabouts by any means:

I go (by using my feet).
I go by car.
I go by train.
I go by ship.

and so on. On the contrary in German "gehen" only means change your whereabouts by using your feet - to walk. Everything else (train, ship, car, ...) is "fahren" or - in case of the airplane - "fliegen". Still, "fahren" is the more general verb and you could say:

Ich fahre in den Urlaub.

even if you go by plane a part of the distance. If you mean the specific part where you use an airplane you have to say:

Ich fliege von New York nach London.

There is also a figurative

Ich gehe nach Deutschland.

but this has more the connotation of "to relocate" than to (just) travel there.
Another quirk is that to "heim/nach Hause gehen" is a sort-of fixed phrase and hence can be used even despite you drive, fly or use any other sorts of relocation to get there. In "nach Hause gehen" "gehen" has a similar scope of meaning as in English.
The same is true for other (sort-of) fixed phrases like "Geh weg!" (Go away!) which means rather "put some distance between you and me" than commanding the other to walk. In the same category: "Geh zum Teufel!" (literally "go to the devil" - go to hell).

I think in general German tends to more specific in describing things than English. You can just "go" somewhere, you "drive"; you can just "be" somewhere, you "stand". If fact it seems like you can't move a muscle in German without adding a "hin" or "her" or "rien" or "raus" or whatever. This is a bit counterintuitive for English speakers since German seems to have perfectly good translations of "go" and "be", but it leads to word for word translations between German and English not working well. Of course there are a lot of other reasons that word for word translations usually don't work.

@RDBury: I think it is not by chance that most modern-day philosophers (say, 16th century onwards) are of German language. Wittgenstein (one of them) said "Die Grenzen meiner Sprache sind die Grenzen meiner Welt." My English vocabulary is a far cry from being adequate, but I always had the feeling that German lends itself better to expressing nuances. Maybe that is just me, though.

No. You can't use gehen with vehicles. Use fahren for those. Use reisen if you don't want to specify the mode of transportation and the distance travelled is rather large.

Sie ist nach Hause gefahren.

This means she took a vehicle (bicycle, car, train etc.). A plane also fits, that fahren means the same as reisen then.
Gehen on the other hand is chiefly walking and only in some rare contexts as e.g.

Er geht nach Hause.
Geh zum Teufel!

the mode of transportation isn't specified by gehen.

Fahren und Flugzeug? Das passt nicht.

Wenn du in den USA bist, sagst du auch Ich fahre bald nach Hause. und meinst selbstverständlich ein Flugzeug.

"You can't use gehen with vehicles. (...) only in some rare contexts (...) the mode of transportation isn't specified by gehen." - not so rare, I'd say. An exchange like "Wir gehen im Sommer nach Vietnam." - "Wie geht ihr dorthin?" - "Mit dem Flugzeug." sounds natural, but the crucial point seems to be that "gehen" is not used to concretely describe the mode of travel here.
